# Any way to view files within trash bin? (macOS)

Tags: macos

Is there any way to view file in the trash can without dragging out it out? Any commands that can enable this?

[image: image link]

Comment: Note: 'anyway' and 'any way' have two distinct meanings. The one you want here is 'any way'. https://www.dictionary.com/e/anyway-vs-anyways-vs-any-way/ *[see edit history]*

Answer (score 0):

For images, text etc, QuickLook works.

Select, tap the spacebar. Tap again to hide, or down arrow to select the next object

Screenshot of this question, trashed, then QuickLook'd…

[image]

Comment: True, this is definitely one solution; never realized! I think macOS prevents opening apps (not files) in the trash bin. If there is like a command for it, I think that will solve the problem completely!

Comment: It's a safety issue. Trying to open or launch something in the trash is really not good behaviour for the machine [or discipline for the user] What happens if the trash gets emptied whilst it's open? For QuickLook it will just close when it has nothing to do. the same would not be true for an executable, so the OS simply stops you from jeopardising the integrity. Don't throw away things you still need would be the real solution ;)